# Firefox desktop entry not updating

Tags: firefox, icons, 22.04, .desktop

I want to change the icon of the firefox application menu shortcut, and I edited the desktop entry for that: changed the `Icon=firefox` to `Icon=firefox-nightly`. When I replaced the `firefox.desktop` file with the edited version in `/usr/share/applications` the icon does not update in the application menu. Any mistakes I might be making? I'm sure the new file and edits are in place.

Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You tagged `Unity` which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @24601 I don't know whether the dock name changes with versions, but I've specified my Ubuntu version, 22.04.

Comment: 22.04 uses the GNOME DE by default. FYI FF is the snap version not deb by default so you may need to explain in your question what steps you have taken. Don't add the info to the comment train.. [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, changing `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` is wrong in all cases, even if in some circumstances, that would do what you want. The reason is that the directory `/usr/share/applications/` is managed by the APT package management system. Any of your changes to that file may be overwritten by a future update. The correct way would be to edit a copy of that file, a copy located in `~/.local/share/applications` if the change is to affect only yourself as user, or in `/usr/local/share/applications` if the change is to affect all users.

Second, while your action could have caused the desired effect, it does not because you are now using Firefox installed as a **snap package**. The file that enables the firefox menu entry is now `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop`. To change the icon, copy that file to one of the directories mentioned before, and edit the copy.